# Is it possible to manage another PC with windows 10 using python?

Tags: windows, automation, remote-access

As in the title, I am an IT Specialist in the company and we want to automate some tasks we are doing on daily basis which takes ages. We've created some script but they are working fine locally.

How to connect to remote PC with windows 10 with python to execute commands using cmd/powershell.

The best option would be without installing any additional programs like python etc.

As far as we tried wmi which is not working on computers with windows 10 or pypsexec which force us to install python on remote computers.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)? I've no idea if that uses WMI under the covers though or some other mechanism though.

Comment: What would your proposed Python solution look like? Everyone would have a Python service running on their PC waiting for you to issue remote commands to it? And it doesn't sound to me like pypsexec forces you to install Python on remote computers, only the computer that's doing the administration.

Comment: Perfect solution for me is to run script on my pc, enter name/ip of the host, admin login and pass to execute commands like cmd/powershell on remote.